# is HTTP more efficient than MQTT

Tags: http, mqtt

is HTTP better than MQTT and why someone should choose HTTP over MQTT is it more efficient? when we use HTTP and when we use MQTT ?. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. long tradition, popularity & thausends of software 2. they differ in model synchronous/asyn, request-response fit better to typical thinking

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your use case and both are powerful on their own areas. HTTP is technically for web and MQTT is used in IOT. MQTT is generally used when you want your messages to be lightweight as its packet size is very low.